# PHP&MySQL: останется ли открытым SQL-соединение, если уйти со страницы со скриптом?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Останется ли открытым MySQL-соединение в приведенном ниже коде после того, как мы уйдём со страницы со скриптом?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
$mysqli -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// манипулируем с БД
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.location.href = \"http://localhost/oterpage.php\" </script>";
$mysqli -> close();
```

Я сделал переадесацию через JS, потому что до этого кода у меня уже был вывод в браузер и из-за этого `header` нельзя использовать.

Comment: После того как скрипт полностью отработает, php убьет соединение с БД. Помоему он это сделает и без $mysqli -> close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP код выполняется после получения сервером HTTP запроса. После того как запрос полностью получен и передан интерпретатору PHP браузер клиента уже никак не может повлиять на выполнение PHP кода. Всё что он может это сделать её один запрос.
Так-что после того как интерпретатор сделает `echo` он сделает `$mysqli -> close();` что приведёт к закрытию соединения с БД.

Comment: Отлично всё объяснили! Спасибо Вам за ответ!